# Can’t start Mathematica 9

Tags: mathematica

While opening Mathematica 9, it says:

> /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/Mathematica: /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16)

Answer (score 2):

You should try these command:

```
1. cd /usr/local/wolfram/mathematica/9.0/systemfiles/libraries/linux-x86-64

2. sudo mv libz.so.1 libz.so.1.old

3. sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
```

from https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/bodhi-92/mathematica-installation-tip-%60zlib_1-2-9%27-not-found-4175639130/